# How to get container id from first docker-compose service inside second service?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, filebeat

I want to run filebeat as a sidecar container next to my main application container to collect application logs. I'm using docker-compose to start both services together, filebeat depending on the application container.

This is all working fine. I'm using a shared volume for the application logs.
However I would like to collect docker container logs (stdout JSON driver) as well in filebeat.

Filebeat provides a docker/container input module for this purpose. Here is my configuration. First part is to get the application logs. Second part should get docker logs:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  paths:
    - /path/to/my/application/*.log.json
  exclude_lines: ['DEBUG']

- type: docker
  containers.ids: '*'
  json.message_key: message
  json.keys_under_root: true
  json.add_error_key: true
  json.overwrite_keys: true
  tags: ["docker"]
```

What I don't like it the `containers.ids: '*'`. Here I would want to point filebeat to the direct application container, ignoring all others.
Since I don't know the container ID before I run `docker-compose up` starting both containers, I was wondering if there is a easy way to get the container ID from my application container in my filebeat container (via docker-comnpose?) to filter on this ID?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may work around the problem:

first set all the logs from the contianer to a syslog:

```
driver: "syslog"
  options:
    syslog-address: "tcp://localhost:9000"
```

then configure filebeat to get the logs from that syslog server like this:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: syslog
  protocol.udp:
    host: "localhost:9000"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also not really answering the question, but should work as a solution as well.

The main idea is to **use label within the filebeat autodiscovery** filter.

Taken from this post: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filebeat-autodiscovery-filtering-by-container-labels/120201/5

`filebeat.yml`

```
filebeat.autodiscover:
  providers:
    - type: docker
      templates:
        - condition:
            contains:
              docker.container.labels.somelabel: "somevalue"
          config:
            - type: docker
              containers.ids:
                - "${data.docker.container.id}"

output.console:
  pretty: true
```

`docker-compose.yml:`

```
version: '3'

services:
  filebeat:
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:6.2.1
    command: "--strict.perms=false -v -e -d autodiscover,docker"
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ./filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
      - /var/lib/docker/containers:/var/lib/docker/containers
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  test:
    image: alpine
    command: "sh -c 'while true; do echo test; sleep 1; done'"
    depends_on:
      - filebeat
    labels:
      somelabel: "somevalue"
```